# SQL Server 2014 Express connection to server

Tags: sql-server, connection

Please help me to issue for connect to SQL Server 2014 Express. In screenshots you can see my settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager and screenshots for connection.

**Screenshots**:

```
http://imgur.com/9L8KeoD
http://imgur.com/hA5rOBW
http://imgur.com/8iZcBr5
http://imgur.com/9eJTcDB
http://imgur.com/NGGe1IC
http://imgur.com/X49Fxh8
http://imgur.com/a2eeuOn
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Does the instance have remote connections enabled?

[image]

Comment: I can't open Server Properties because there isn't any options I can't connect to server. Please see screenshot(http://imgur.com/nhI3RCN).

Comment: You should be able to connect with SSMS on the host server.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial about adding connection to Fire Wall helped me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIovZluNmNs

Now I can see my Login.

Thanks.